# Django ModelAdmin objects reused for subsequent requests in Unittests?

Tags: python, django, python-unittest

I'm trying to reproduce an (obvious) problem in a ModelAdmin with Unittests.

In the ModelAdmin, I perform some extra operations when saving a model. In doing so, I introduce the new instance variable `collection_page`.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def save_model(self, requset, obj, form, change):
        ...
        if obj_is_new:
            self.collection_page = ....
        ...
        self.collection_page   # <== AttributeError if obj is not new.
```

I test the module using the `django.test.Client` twice, like this:

```
class CollectionAdminTestCase(django.test.TestCase):
    ...
    def test_redirect_after_editing_existing_object(self):
        self.client.post(
            self.creation_path,
            self.creation_post
        )
        response = self.client.post(
            self.change_path,
            self.change_post
        )
        self.assertEqual(
            response.status_code, 302
        )
```

The test passes, but it should fail.

When I add

```
        try:
            del self.collection_page
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```

at the beginning of the `save_model` method in `MyModelAdmin`, the test fails as it should.

Is this an intended feature of Django? Is there a better way to deal with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should absolutely not be setting state on the ModelAdmin object. It lives for the lifetime of the server process; anything set on it will be preserved across requests.

You don't say what you are doing with this variable, so it's hard to give advice about how best to do whatever it is; only, not this way.

Comment: What I do while saving the model is too complex to do it without instance variables - I create a series of cms pages with a certain content. So, I'll put my logic into the model.  What was handy about the admin is that one has access to the request user. Simply informing the model instance about the user is probably the best idea.